# DB upgrade Error on CIVI CRM 5.66.0 Joomla 4

Tags: upgrade, joomla

On update to civi 5.66.0 on Joomla 4
installation fine on DB upgrade it display error CRM_Core_Permission_Drupal6
Compile Error: Cannot make non static method CRM_Core_Permission_Base::getModulePermissions() static in class CRM_Core_Permission_Drupal6
/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Permission/Drupal6.php:195
[image]

any idea is it bug or any files need to be removed.
Joomla 4.3
error remain same on PHP 7.4 and PHP 8.1, 8.0

Answer (score 1):

These bugs occur when you forget to delete the CiviCRM directory before replacing it with the new one. The Joomla installer, unfortunately, does not do this for you, so an obsolete file such as `CRM/Core/Permission/Drupal6.php` which has been deleted in the new version of CiviCRM will stick around on your server, causing problems.

You must *delete* the entire `civicrm` directory and replace it with the new one, to make sure old files are properly deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Colman for your answer. But how to do to not loose :

- customizations ?
- extension ?

Of course, we have to keep both settings files.

And in Joomla!, you have to think do delete `civicrm` in component, in administrator/component and in media. Is there another location to delete `civicrm` ?

Comment: Hi not in media. as media folder has extensions. only delered admin component and it work

Comment: Thank you JoomPS. If I delete admin component folder, I loose plugins and extensions ?!?

Comment: That's it : in /administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/ i find an ext subfolder and some plugins are missing after deleting components/com_civicrm folders. I don't know why I have /administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/ext/ and /media/civicrm/ext/
After moving ext subfolder, I delete both components/com_civicrm and then upgrade CiviCRM and reinstall l10n and everything is allright.

Answer (score 0):

Only copy setting.php in Joomla admin civi folder.
do not use older folder as it has the older file not removed in the udpates.
the extensions are in the media folder so no change there.